# User Input Search using KML overlay on Google Map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, kml

I've created "zones" laid out in a `KML` file that effectively overlays on the Google Map within my page. What I am looking to do is provide the ability for users to search by inputting their address in an html form and having the code recognize that their address is either in "zone a", "b", etc. or not in one at all by creating a placemarker at the location the searched for and including the appropriate information in the description.

I've tried using `javascript` to transform their search query to lat and long and using the geocoder function, create a placemarker that way, but have been unsuccessful. I thought maybe there was a problem because the KML layer would have already been loaded possible requiring a refresh of the data...? So I tried using `php` to `POST` to the same page causing essentially a refresh of it with their query included and having the geocoder create a placemarker at user's lat and long THEN load the `KML` layer.

After too long of spinning wheels, it seems I need to consider an option other than KML, but I'm not sure how I would implement fusion tables or throw the KML information into a mysql database.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html) (uses the [geoxml3 third party KML parser](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)).

[Version (same functionality) using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)

Comment: Geocodezip, I actually told the client that this functionality could be done (although I wasn't sure how) based on showing the example you posted! I've used many of your posts in trying to find the best way to do this, however am unsure of how to implement the code. Oddly, I was really hoping you would involve yourself in this conversation because you seem to be very knowledgeable on this subject. Obviously, I need to spend more time researching so that I understand the geoxml3 process better.

Comment: P.S. I believe I actually used a resource you supply on your website to create the kml file to begin with!